# My code doesn't seem to work perfectly (always same message)

Tags: c

Hello guys i got this code , i want to check if it's perfect array

```
perfect array means that the sum of his cases of one line equal the sum of the first case of each line
```

i tried to full the array with numbers then compare it's sum with the actual sum of it really meets
the issue is no matter what i type it displays that it's a perfect array even if it's not . HELP please  i'm stuck here .

```c
#include<stdio.h>

#define l 10
#define c 15
int main() {
  int T[l][c];
  int i, j, som, sl, sc, n;
  bool prl, prc; //parfait ligne ..
  
  // Saisie des données de tb matrice 
  printf("Dimension de la matrice carree (max.50) : ");
  scanf("%d", & n);
  
  //triatemnt de tb matrice
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      printf("Element[%d][%d] : ", j, j);
      scanf("%d", & T[i][j]);
    }
    
  // traitement de matrise parfait
  som = 0;
  for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
    som += T[1][j];
  }
  
  i = 2;
  prl = true;
  while (i <= n && prl) {
    som = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < l; j++) {
      som += T[i][j];
    }
    if (som != sl) {
      prl = false;
    }
    i += 1;
  }
  
  j = 2;
  prc = true;
  while (j <= c && prc) {
    som = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
      som += T[i][j];
    }
    if (som != sc) {
      prc = false;
    }
    j += 1;
  }
  
  // affiche si parfait ou non 
  if (prl || prc) {
    printf("matrice parfaite \n");
  } else
    printf("matrice non parfaite \n");
    
  // Affichage de la tb matrice 
  printf("Matrice donnee :\n");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
      printf("%7d", T[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't initialize (or even ever set) `sl` or `sc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well basiclly after checking your code , it seems that you have init those two values to 0

```
int sl=0,sc=0;
```

secondly when i printed them i noticed that they get random values (try it by yourself)

```
 printf("SL = %d , SC = %d",sl,sc);
```

so i advice you to recheck your algorithm as your whole code didn't include them having any value but you still yet  compare them to your sum .

```
if (som!=sc) {
      prc=false;
             }
```

also here

```
  if (som!=sl) {
      prl=false;
             }
```

I'm not aware of your perfect array, but i guess sc and sl should be included in a for loop and add them some sum of what you wanted to compare them to

also i have noticed that you always open the brackets . it's not wrong , but it's not always correct as you need to take a note that if your action includes one statement (action) simply write it directly
exemple from your code :

```
 for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
  som += T[i][j];
}
```

can be direcly to

```
 for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
  som += T[i][j];
```

Comment: Your answer seems logic . Thanks a lot for helping . But i'm not sure what to add exactly to them

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the array out of bounds here

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    for (j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
     printf("Element[%d][%d] : ",j,j);
     scanf("%d", &T[i][j]);
    }
```

You should have

```
for (i=0; i<l && i<n; i++)
    for (j=0; j<c && j<n; j++)
    {
     printf("Element[%d][%d] : ",i,j);
     scanf("%d", &T[i][j]);
    }
```

And you could calculate the sum straight away

```
int perfect = 1;

scanf("%d", &T[0][0]);
for (i=0; i<l && i<n; i++)
    som = T[i][0];
    for (j=1; j<c && j<n; j++)
    {
        printf("Element[%d][%d] : ",i,j);
        scanf("%d", &T[i][j]);
        som += T[i][j];
    }
    if( i+1<l && i+1<n && scanf("%d", &T[i+1][0]) == 1 ) {
        if( som != T[i+1][0] ) {
            perfect = 0;
            printf("matrice non parfaite \n");
            break;
        }
    }
    else {
        puts("Error.");
        break;
    }
}

if( perfect ) {
  printf("matrice parfaite \n");
}
```